# How would I copy the contents of a Listbox row in Tkinter which the user selects to the windows clipboard

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to make a Tkinter Listbox where if the user clicks (preferably double clicks) on a row the contents of that row would be copied to the clipboard.

Here is example code of what I need help with:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
def listbox_copy():
    app.clipboard_clear()
    app.clipboard_append(listbox[1])

listbox = Listbox(app)
list = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
for c in list:
    listbox.insert(END,c)
listbox.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: listbox_copy())

app.mainloop()
```

Right now I'm getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\elias\Desktop\test.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: listbox_copy())
  File "C:\Users\elias\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in listbox_copy
    app.clipboard_append(listbox[1])
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: tkinter has functions for manipulating the clipboard. Is there a reason you're using pyperclip instead? Are you specifically asking about manipulating the clipboard, or are you really asking about the `can only concatenate` error message?

Comment: @acw1668 I just posted the full message. Also I'm using general terms because I made an example code for this stack overflow post. My original code is pretty lengthy and involves many functions so I didn't want to post it here.

Comment: The error states that the argument passed to `app.clipboard.append(...)` is incorrect.  Should it be `listbox.get(ANCHOR)` instead of `listbox[1]`.

Comment: I don't think `listbox[1]` is what you think it is. Have you examined it to verify your assumptions?  What do you think `listbox[1]` is supposed to do?

Comment: @eliasbenb Read up on [The Tkinter Listbox Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the selected item using `listbox.get(ANCHOR)` instead of `listbox[1]`.  If you want to copy the selected item to clipboard when user double-clicks the item, bind `<Double-Button-1>` instead of `<<ListboxSelect>>`:

```
def listbox_copy(event):
    app.clipboard_clear()
    selected = listbox.get(ANCHOR)
    app.clipboard_append(selected)

...

listbox.bind('<Doubld-Button-1>', listbox_copy)
```

Comment: Thank you, I decided to use a combobox instead of a list box using this method and it worked